# Is System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory culture specific?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, json

Looks like that JsonValueProviderFactory (from Microsoft.Web.Mvc) that I'm using in my ASP.NET MVC2 project is culture specific.

I send this JSON from client:

```
{
   "name": "Max",
   "weight": "60.21" 
}
```

JsonValueProviderFactory converts JSON to this class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works correctly if my current culture is CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. But if I explicitly set my culture to "ru-RU" User's Weight value will be 0.0

Ok, I can send formatted value based on culture for weight from client, for example:

```
{
   "name": "Max",
   "weight": "1,100.21"    // it's just example, not my real weight :) 
}
```

But in this case JsonValueProviderFactory can't parse weight and it will be zero, although double.Parse("1,100.21", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) works correctly.

How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `weight` property is supposed to be double, send it as such, not as string:

```
var model = {
   "name": "Max",
   "weight": 60.21
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("someAction")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```